# Change the hover color of SVG image in SCSS with SVG Inject

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I'm trying to change the hover color of a SVG Image and apply other settings using SCSS and SVG Inject but not working.

My HTML:

```
div class="nav-social">
    <img src="/assets/facebook.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)"/>
    <img src="/assets/instagram.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)"/>
    <img src="/assets/youtube.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)"/>
    <img src="/assets/twitter.svg" onload="SVGInject(this)"/>
</div>
```

My SCSS:

```
.nav-social {
    display: flex;

    svg{
        margin-left: 16px;
        width: 24px;

        cursor: pointer;

        path, circle{
            transition: .5s ease;
        }

        &:hover{
            path, circle{
                fill: red;
                transform: translate3d(0, -2px, 0);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

None of the effects that came after calling SVG is applyed on the svg images. And I can't find a solution.

Comment: `SVGInject()` isn't a native javascript function. Are you loading the appropriate JS library and have you confirmed it's working?

Comment: post source code of SVGInject()  for better clarity

Comment: yes everything is set up right. I already review this several times

Comment: I would recommend to open the svg file in a text editor and copy it from there to the html file. then you can add classes and do manipulations as you like. If you like I can upload an example

Comment: iceweasel I am using the  minified version (v1.2.3) of SVGInject available at https://github.com/iconfu/svg-inject

Comment: Post the relevant section of HTML from your page **after the SVG has been injected.**  At the moment, the most likely explanation is that the injection is not occurring.  So we need evidence that it is.